# How to swizzle NSError init without hitting an infinite loop

Tags: ios, swift, nserror, method-swizzling

How to call the original `NSError` init method when swizzling?

My current implementation

```
 extension NSError {

    @objc class func errorSwizzle() {
        guard let instance = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(NSError.init(domain:code:userInfo:))),
            let swizzleInstance = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(NSError.init(swizzleDomain:code:info:))) else { return }
        method_exchangeImplementations(instance, swizzleInstance)
    }

    @objc class func errorUnSwizzle() {
        guard let instance = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(NSError.init(domain:code:userInfo:))),
            let swizzleInstance = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(NSError.init(swizzleDomain:code:info:))) else { return }
        method_exchangeImplementations(swizzleInstance, instance)
    }

    @objc convenience init(swizzleDomain: String, code: Int, info: [String : Any]?) {

        /// infinite loop as it calls the swizzled init again.
        self.init(domain: swizzleDomain, code: code, userInfo: info)

        /// Do something.. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exchanged the implementations, that means you have to call:

```
@objc convenience init(swizzleDomain: String, code: Int, info: [String : Any]?) {
    self.init(swizzleDomain: swizzleDomain, code: code, info: info)
}
```

Because `self.init(swizzleDomain:...)` will contain the original initializer.

Comment: Thanks, @Sulthan, just found my issue as well and posted that as an answer